# How to solve such complicated integral to get closed form expression.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, solution-verification, special-functions

I am trying to solve the following integral to obtain the closed form expression but not getting it correctly.

$P = \biggl[\int_0^\infty\biggl[\frac{e^\delta \sigma_1}{\sqrt{\alpha^2\sigma^2_2\sigma^2_3}}\biggl(\sum_{d=0}^\infty W_{-d-0.5}(2\delta)\cdot\gamma\bigl(1+d,\frac{\gamma_s(1+x)-1}{A\sigma^2_1}\bigr)\biggr)\biggr]^N\times\frac{\biggl[e^{\delta-\frac{x}{A_1\sigma^2_4}}\cdot M\cdot\bigl(\frac{x}{A_1\sigma^2_4}\bigr)^d\cdot W_{-d-0.5}(2\delta)\biggl(\frac{e^{\delta}\sigma_4 \gamma(1+d,\frac{x}{A_1 \sigma^2_4})W_{-d-0.5,0}(2\delta)}{\sqrt{\alpha^2\sigma^2_5\sigma^2_2}}\biggr)^{M-1}\biggr]}{A_1\sigma_4\sqrt{\alpha^2\sigma^2_5\sigma^2_2}} \text{d}x\biggr]^L$

where $W_{λ,μ}$(⋅) is Whittaker function, $x$ is integration variable and all remaining are constants.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure a closed form solution exists?

Comment: I am trying for it .....but not getting it correctly....